# iOS: wrong value for characteristic with low energy bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a low energy bluetooth device which picks up signal comparable to a heart-monitoring device. This data is plotted in real-time on a separate plotting screen.

My issue is that I think the values I'm getting from the hardware is wrong.

In my method didUpdateValueForCharacteristic a few lines of relevant info is:

```
case TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_X_UUID: // x value characteristic 
 {
   UInt8 xval[20];                
   [characteristic.value getBytes:&xval length:TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_READ_LEN];
```

I then proceed to do some calculations on each value in the array which should each be a byte. Through each iteration (I think 256 Hz) I get 20 bytes of data and this gets pushed into an array of size 20.

These are the values from the `characteristic.value` that I'm getting for all 20 bytes:

```
[0] UInt8   '\x9b'  
[1] UInt8   '\xe1'  
[2] UInt8   '\xba'  
[3] UInt8   '9' 
[4] UInt8   '\x01'  
[5] UInt8   '\0'    
[6] UInt8   '\0'    
[7] UInt8   '\0'    
[8] UInt8   '\x01'  
[9] UInt8   '\0'    
[10]    UInt8   '\0'    
[11]    UInt8   '\0'    
[12]    UInt8   '\b'    
[13]    UInt8   'M' 
[14]    UInt8   '\xd5'  
[15]    UInt8   '''
[16]    UInt8   '\x1f'  
[17]    UInt8   '\xe6'  
[18]    UInt8   '\xbb'  
[19]    UInt8   '9'
```

I'm not sure what these values are actually representing. It looks like part is binary and part is *maybe* hexidecimal values of addresses. 
All I know is that I can multiply these values by other integers and somehow get a constant string of the same numbers.

```
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,8,125,214,39,31,230,187,57,49,225,186,57
```

But this isn't the value that I want. I'm kind of lost, I've tried switching the characteristic.value to characteristic.valueHandle and other things, but I think it should be importing the data into the portion of value so the way it's written should be good.

I've also tried changing the `TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_X_UUID` to other characteristics like ...Y_UUID but I'm pretty sure it should be obtaining the relevant data from X_UUID.

Anyways, any help at all or pointing me in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I am seeing that TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_READ_LEN should only by 1.

```
case TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_X_UUID: {
    char xval;
    [characteristic.value getBytes:&xval length:TI_KEYFOB_ACCEL_READ_LEN];
    float x = (float)xval;
    ...
```